# Questions about fascia & soffit repair

Tags: soffit, fascia

This is a porch roof, single layer, 54 year old house.  Started tearing off rotting fascia and found a sub-fascia rotted as well.  Also took off soffit in that area.  All the rot is at the end, by the fascia.  Pic 1 shows rot (NOTE:  oddly, the soffit and gutter of the house (upper) roof showed up in the pic and it looks odd, so I labeled it so no one gets confused (just ignore that part).  I looked up into the roof and most of the sheathing is good, except the last 3 inches--some parts have rot (pic 2 shows this).  Noting is moist--the sub-fasica & fascia rot is bone dry.

[edit]:  Perhaps a clue to the original problem:  I just examined the removed soffit and it had about 6 inches of black on it and that part was dirty.  Maybe water sat there?

First question:  what caused this?  I'd like to know in case there's some other repair I need to do.  Because it's bone dry, maybe the issue was addressed at some point in the past?

Second question:  the porch roof is cupped a bit at the end where the gutter was.  Once stuff was removed, I confirmed the sheathing appears to have rotted at the end.  I plan to roof next year.  Is there anything I should do about this NOW (maybe before I put new soffit, sub-fascia & fascia on)?

Third question:  The horizontal parts that the soffit is nailed to (see '?' in first pic) are loose--I can rotate them a bit by hand because they only have one nail at each end.  Is this an issue?  I don't think so because they seem to be only there to hold up the soffit, but since I'm here, I'll ask.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An update:  one thing I did do before I fixed everything and sealed things up was to spray the sheathing with a borax solution because I could see traces of mold on it.